# Why do bosons and fermions exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, fermions, bosons

if i have two particles in states: |1> and |2> respectavly , and they are not identical then the combined state is |1>|2> , 
but if they are identical then the labels 1 or 2 are arbitrary and could be swapped so **supposedly** we get two options:

- bosons   = |1>|2> + |2>|1>
- fermions = |1>|2> - |2>|1>

Why there are only these two options ? can't you have any arbitrary superposition of the two states ? (eg: a|1>|2> + b|2>|1> , a*a + b*b = 1)

Comment: Have a look at the [spin-statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) and [anyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon).

Comment: This is also kinda covered in the [Wikipedia entry on *identical particles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Quantum_mechanical_description_of_identical_particles).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must fermions be antisymmetric?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207459/) It is not a result of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: wikipdia says that it is just a fact of life that all particles are either bosons or fermions.

Comment: Let's not propose this as a duplicate of a closed question, @NeuroFuzzy.  Other possibly-related questions include http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77950/44126, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4049/44126

Answer (score -1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Quantum_mechanical_description_of_identical_particles) states:

> It appears to be a fact of nature that identical particles do not occupy states of a mixed symmetry.