# On the Robertson uncertainty relation when $\big|\dfrac{1}{2} \langle\{A,B\}\rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \big|^2 \neq 0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The Robertson uncertainty relation is

$\sigma^2_A \sigma^2_B \geq \big|\dfrac{1}{2} \langle\{A,B\}\rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \big|^2 + \big| \dfrac{1}{2i} \langle [A,B] \rangle \big|^2.$

Where $\sigma^2_X$ is the variance of the operator $X$ and $\{A,B\}$,  $[A,B]$ are the anti-commutator and the commutator of the Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$, respectively.

The uncertainty relation is more commom presented in the form

$\sigma^2_A \sigma^2_B \geq \big| \dfrac{1}{2i} \langle [A,B] \rangle \big|^2.$

Where there are commom physical examples which have that satisfied, e.g. $[x,p] \geq \dfrac{\hbar}{2}$, but these examples have $\big|\dfrac{1}{2} \langle\{A,B\}\rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \big|^2=0$.

I am trying to find a quantum system where the term $\big|\dfrac{1}{2} \langle\{A,B\}\rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \big|^2 \neq 0$, so that the lowest limit of the product of the variances of $A$ and $B$ have a dependence on the latter. So, to answer my question, it is necessary to give a possible physical system where $\big|\dfrac{1}{2} \langle\{A,B\}\rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \big|^2 \neq 0$ for $A$ and $B$ Hermitian.

Any help or ideas are welcome.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/meaning-of-the-anti-commutator-term-in-the-uncertainty-principle?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might profit from calculating a few expectation values for, e.g. the oscillator, for which $a^\dagger |n\rangle= \sqrt{n+1} | n+1\rangle$.
Take $A=a$ and $B=a^\dagger$, so that
$$
[a,a^\dagger ]=1, \qquad \{ a,a^\dagger \} =a a^\dagger + a^\dagger a=1+2N.
$$

Look at the first excited state, $|1\rangle$, so $a|1\rangle=|0\rangle$, so your expectation values are 
$$
\langle 1| a|1\rangle=\langle 1|a^\dagger| 1\rangle=0,\\
\langle 1| \{ a,a^\dagger \} |1\rangle= 3,\\
\langle 1| [a,a^\dagger ]|1\rangle= 1,
$$
so that, for this state 
$$
\sigma_a^2 \sigma^2_{a^\dagger}\geq 9/4 +1/4= 10/4.
$$ 
The anticommutator, of course, is *not a constant*, unlike the commutator, nor should you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the attention and how would I interpret $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ as physical quantities in this example?

Comment: They are the [usual linear combinations of *x* and *p*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method). You could rerun all this with plain *x* and *p* on the 1st excited site of the oscillator, the first termite polynomial times the usual Gaussian....